# Web 8.5 XPM error show up after click create button

Tags: dxa, web8.5, experience-manager, dxa-1.6

We are facing an issue that when creating a page via XPM, the error message showed up. (see attached screenshot attachment-1.jpg).
They checked the content management and found that actually the page was created successfully, but in XPM, error message still shows up without further updates.

We tried to change the config on the presentation server by increase  value but still have an error.
"cd_storage_conf.xml file" timeout setting under path "D:\SDLWeb\discoveryStaging\config".

[image]

Comment: The page can be created on CM side, maybe it can have delays generating the new page. Is there any related configuration we can change it to get rid of this error message?

Comment: Can you make sure your session preview and session content cd storage configuration are same and try to  check the logs of the session preview

Comment: refer to the link -->  refer to the https://gateway.sdl.com/CommunityKnowledge?articleName=000006516

Comment: This error message indeed trying to connect the preview service from cms and then it shows that error message. Try to ensure preview service should be accessible from cms and ensure preview service configured and registered with discovery.

Comment: @Brian I agree with Velmurugan please check and add your comments .

Comment: @Velmurugan, Anand NS, thank you very much for your reply. based on you comment, I did another test, I remove the role "PreviewWebServiceCapability" in preview/ config file,restarted services, Now I can see the same errow when I click XPM create button. so Indeed this error can be caused by preview service. let me check customer's environment's configuration.

Comment: @Brian  thanks for the response first make sure the preview service is running and on the discovery try to make sure the service is registered . Refer https://docs.sdl.com/792468/344707/sdl-web-8--retired-/the-discovery-registration-tool for more details . Provide your feedback after to verify the customer environment.

Comment: @Anand NS, very appreciate your comment, I already request customer to check it on their side. keep you posted.

Comment: @ Anand NS, customer still have same error message show up.....I am still checking.